# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java. library.path

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

i am trying to make **jdbc oci connection** to **oracle 11g** that uses **os authentication**

i made a sample console application to test the connection on some client machine

i developed the application on machine that has **jdk 6** and used in the project the jar **ojdbc6.jar**.

the code i am using to connect to database is as follows:

```
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
String tnsName="Prod";
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:oci:/@"+tnsName);
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

i am trying to run this application from client machine that has the oracle11g installed, and the oracle home is set on path to be:  **C:\orant\jdk\bin**

also the path: **C:\orant\bin** contains **oci.dll** and doesn't contain **ocijdbc11.dll**

the client has jre7 installed and doesn't have jdk.

when trying to run the above code on client machine that is os authenticated to oracle database i am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.
library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3178)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java
:3174)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:233)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:
508)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:133)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtensio
n.java:53)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSou
rce.java:275)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java
:206)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java
:156)
        at auth.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

please advise how can i fix this exception.

Comment: You should have `ocijdbc.dll` as part of your Oracle installation; I'm not sure where it goes in Windows but in Linux it's under `ORACLE_HOME/lib`. You need whichever directory that is in on your `PATH` too, I think. I don't have an environment to check that though so I'm not quite sure. Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361166/266304) might work...

Comment: Could be a 32 bit <> 64 bit problem. What is the bitness of that dll and of your Java? BTW: `ocijdbc11` is a symbol name, it does not necessarily match the file name.

Comment: @Alex Poole,@Mark Rotteveel i can't find ocijdbc11.dll on the client machine ? please suggest solutions to try.

Comment: @Alex Poole,@Mark Rotteveel i think that there are other way to make connection without requiring the dll, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to make successful os connection to oracle database with jdbc in this post:

[How to connect to oracle database with os authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252177/how-to-connect-to-oracle-database-with-os-authentication/19265449#19265449)

Answer (score 3):

If you use an OCI url(`"jdbc:oracle:oci:/@"+tnsName`) then you need oracle client libraries on the classpath. So you need have oracle client on the machine.

But if you use a thin driver and specify the url as the following, you don't need the oracle client.

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+dbServer+":"+port+":"+SID;
```

Answer (score 0):

try set correct values in /`usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat.conf` for ld_path:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/usr/lib64"
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Eclipse with Jboss 6.1.0 disturbution .it will shown error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.
library.path
Solution :
copy ocijdbc11.dll from oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN and paste in to

D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this problem because you are using JRE 1.6 or below version of Java with type-2 driver. Please replace your JRE 1.6 buildpath by JRE 1.7 or JRE 1.8. It will solve the problem.

Please follow the steps:

1. Right Click on your project folder
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on java build path.
4. Select "jre system library" which is jre 1.6 or below from libraries and remove it cause this is becoming the source of cause.
5. Now click add library
6. Click jre system library
7. Click next
8. Select execution environment as JavaSE-1.8(jre1.8.0_144) by clicking environment button and then press ok.
9. Click installed jre button
10. Select jre1.8 from it (if jre1.8 is not present the click on add button and add it).
11. Click Finish.
12. Click ok.
13. valah! you will find your code running.